# Double click cell to return cell contents into another cell (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to be able to double-click a cell and have the cell value/text be returned into another cell.

My code so far is:

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
 If Intersect(Target, Range("E:P")) Is Nothing Then
 Else
    ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S13")
 End If
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that I want the actual cell contents, not necessarily the numeric value.

For instance, in cell E12, I have the text "Completed", but when I double click E12, a "0" gets returned in cell S13 and not the text "Completed".

Comment: Seems that your original cell contains a formula and you want to copy its value not the formula. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with A.S.H "your original cell contains a formula".

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:P")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 then
            Cancel = True
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S13") = Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:P")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S13")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought about using `Cancel = True`.  +1Kudos